# How do I implement Ord for a struct?

Tags: rust

I've seen a question similar to this one, but no one that tells me exactly how to implement `Ord` for a struct. For example, the following:

```
struct SomeNum {
    name: String,
    value: u32,
}

impl Ord for SomeNum {
    fn cmp(&self, other:&Self) -> Ordering {
        let size1 = self.value;
        let size2 = other.value;
        if size1 > size2 {
            Ordering::Less
        }
        if size1 < size2 {
            Ordering::Greater
        }
        Ordering::Equal
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
error: the trait `core::cmp::Eq` is not implemented for the type `SomeNum` [E0277]
```

How would I fix this? I have tried changing the implementation to:

```
impl Ord for SomeNum where SomeNum: PartialOrd + PartialEq + Eq {...}
```

and adding the appropriate `partial_cmp` and `eq` functions but it gives me the error that both those methods are not a member of `Ord`.

Comment: *I've seen a question similar to this one but* - please **include links to these questions** once you've found them. That allows answerers to get a better sense of what explanations you have already read that don't make sense, otherwise we are at risk of just repeating the same thing you already know, wasting everyone's time! It is also nice for future searchers, as they can easily go to related questions.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The definition of [`Ord`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) is this:

```rust
pub trait Ord: Eq + PartialOrd<Self> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering;
}
```

Any type that implements `Ord` must also implement `Eq` and `PartialOrd<Self>`. You must implement these traits for `SomeNum`.

Incidentally, your implementation looks like being the wrong way round; if `self.value` is all you are comparing, `self.value > other.value` should be `Greater`, not `Less`.

You can use the `Ord` implementation on `u32` to assist, should you desire it: `self.value.cmp(other.value)`.

You should also take into account that `Ord` is a [*total* ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). If your `PartialEq` implementation, for example, takes `name` into consideration, your `Ord` implementation must also. It might be well to use a tuple for convenience (indicating that the most important field in the comparison is `value`, but that if they are the same, `name` should be taken into account), something like this:

```rust
struct SomeNum {
    name: String,
    value: u32,
}

impl Ord for SomeNum {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        (self.value, &self.name).cmp(&(other.value, &other.name))
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for SomeNum {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for SomeNum {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        (self.value, &self.name) == (other.value, &other.name)
    }
}

impl Eq for SomeNum { }
```

If you’re doing it like this, you might as well reorder the fields and use `#[derive]`:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct SomeNum {
    value: u32,
    name: String,
}
```

This will expand to basically the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! One more thing. If I wanted to manually calculate cmp, what would I return to signify greater, less, or equal. I've tried doing the above and returning Ordering::Less, Ordering::Greater, and Ordering::Equal when appropriate but the compiler states that cmp expects output type () instead of core::cmp::Ordering. This only seems to happen in the Less and Greater cases that occur in the if statement

Comment: Oh yeah, what you wanted there was `if size1 < size2 { Ordering::Less } else if size1 > size2 { Ordering::Greater } else { Ordering::Equal }`. An `if` expression has a type, you had effectively three statements in a row, the values of the first two of which were not being used, and which had inconsistent types as well, for they had an implicit `else { }` which is of type `()`.

Comment: Is it possible to derive `PartialOrd` from `Ord` and `PartialEq` from `Eq`? Just wrapping their respective return values in `Some`?

Comment: @BallpointBen: well, `Eq` is just a marker that the `PartialEq` implementation is in fact total; for `PartialOrd`, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#how-can-i-implement-partialord. But this is not *deriving*, you’ll need to write the implementation yourself, simple though it be.