# Using max_by_key on a vector of floats

Tags: vector, iterator, rust, max

I want to use `max_by_key` to get the maximum value from a vector of `f64`s based on a certain key. This is a simple example, with a small vector and `abs` as the key:

```
let a: Vec<f64> = vec![-3.0, 0.2, 1.4];
*a.iter().max_by_key(|n| n.abs()).unwrap()
```

However, since `f64` does not implement `Ord`, I get

```
    error[E0277]: the trait bound `f64: std::cmp::Ord` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:15
  |
3 |     *a.iter().max_by_key(|n| n.abs()).unwrap();
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::cmp::Ord` is not implemented for `f64`
```

Similarly, `sort_by_key` fails with the same error:

```
a.sort_by_key(|n| n.abs())
```

I know I can get around the partial ordering restriction to sort a vector of floats with `sort_by`

```
b.sort_by(|m, n| m.partial_cmp(n).unwrap_or(Less))
```

but that would have to be called on a vector `b` for which I've computed the key (in this case `abs`) for each element of `a`, and then I would have to go back and find the corresponding element of `a`, which seems complicated and slow. As the number of items in the list grows, I'd like to minimize passes through the data.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: [Implement `Ord`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884402/how-do-i-implement-ord-for-a-struct) for a wrapper type around the `f64`. This forces you to define how `NaN` is handled. [Examples exist](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28247990/155423) for similar things.

Comment: Do **not** use `.unwrap_or(Less)` — this [gives unstable results in the presence of NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50308360/155423).

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I get the minimum or maximum value of an iterator containing floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446632/how-do-i-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-value-of-an-iterator-containing-floating-poi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not want to create a wrapper type you can use the [ordered_float](https://crates.io/crates/ordered-float) or [ord_subset](https://crates.io/crates/ord_subset) crate. For example

```
extern crate ordered_float;
extern crate ord_subset;

#[test]
fn test_example_() {
    use ordered_float::OrderedFloat;
    // OrderedFloat -> NaN is greater than all other values and equal to itself.
    // NotNaN -> NotNaN::new panics if called with NaN.

    let mut a: Vec<f64> = vec![-3.0, 0.2, 1.4];

    let max = *a.iter().max_by_key(|n| OrderedFloat(n.abs())).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(-3.0, max);

    a.sort_by_key(|n| OrderedFloat(n.abs()));
    assert_eq!(vec![0.2, 1.4, -3.0], a);
}

#[test]
fn test_example_ord_subset() {
    use ord_subset::OrdSubsetIterExt;

    let a: Vec<f64> = vec![-3.0, 0.2, 1.4];

    // For f64, NaN is ignored.
    let max = *a.iter().ord_subset_max_by_key(|n| n.abs()).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(-3.0, max);

    // ord_subset does not help with the sorting problem in the question
}
```

Comment: Seems like no intrinsic way to do this without implementing/including a wrapper type, so I'll accept this. Thanks!