# How to implement the Ord trait without getting the error "use of unstable library feature 'clamp'"?

Tags: rust, clamp

I have a struct that I want to use it as a key in `BTreeMap`, so I implement `PartialEq`, `Eq`, `PartialOrd` and `Ord`. The last causes a problem as there is an unsafe `clamp` trait method.

I implement it this way:

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, Copy, Clone)]
struct Baz(usize);

impl PartialEq for Baz {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0.eq(&other.0)
    }

    fn ne(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0.ne(&other.0)
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Baz {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        self.0.partial_cmp(&other.0)
    }

    fn lt(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0.lt(&other.0)
    }

    fn le(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0.le(&other.0)
    }

    fn gt(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0.gt(&other.0)
    }

    fn ge(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0.ge(&other.0)
    }
}

impl Ord for Baz {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.0.cmp(&other.0)
    }

    fn max(self, other: Self) -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Self(self.0.max(other.0))
    }

    fn min(self, other: Self) -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Self(self.0.min(other.0))
    }

    fn clamp(self, min: Self, max: Self) -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Self(self.0.clamp(min.0, max.0))
    }
}

fn main() {
    Baz(1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db108383e85dd58877126721632220a3)

As far as I know, clamp for integers is safe and should work just fine, but Rust gives me the error

```
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'clamp'
  --> src/main.rs:57:5
   |
57 | /     fn clamp(self, min: Self, max: Self) -> Self
58 | |     where
59 | |         Self: Sized,
60 | |     {
61 | |         Self(self.0.clamp(min.0, max.0))
62 | |     }
   | |_____^
   |
   = note: for more information, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44095

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'clamp'
  --> src/main.rs:61:21
   |
61 |         Self(self.0.clamp(min.0, max.0))
   |                     ^^^^^
   |
   = note: for more information, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44095
```

How can I solve this? I'm using Rust 1.41.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: *an unsafe `clamp` trait method* — it is not `unsafe`, and it's unclear why you think it is.

Comment: Added playground link as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know, clamp for integers is safe and should work just fine, but Rust gives me the error

That's because the [`Ord::clamp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.41.1/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#method.clamp) method is *unstable* — the compiler isn't lying to you. However, that's a method with a [default implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html?highlight=required,method#default-implementations), so you don't need to implement it (and shouldn't, unless you can improve on the default implementation).

Helpfully, there's a section in the documentation for `Ord` titled [How can I implement Ord?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.41.1/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#how-can-i-implement-ord) which describes exactly what you need to do:

> `Ord` requires that the type also be `PartialOrd` and `Eq` (which requires `PartialEq`).
>
> Then you must define an implementation for `cmp()`. You may find it useful to use `cmp()` on your type's fields.

Of special relevance is the fact that `Ord` can be derived:

> This trait can be used with `#[derive]`. When `derive`d on structs, it will produce a lexicographic ordering based on the top-to-bottom declaration order of the struct's members. When `derive`d on enums, variants are ordered by their top-to-bottom declaration order.

Your entire code can likely be

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Copy, Clone)]
struct Baz(usize);
```

See also:

- [How do I implement Ord for a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29884402/155423)
- [Implementing Ord for a type is awkward?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28387711/155423)

Comment: The first link in "See also" worked for me. Thanks a lot!